# Using the results of a query to query another table multiple times (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have two tables and I want to get a result that combined information from both of them. 
In table_one I have 4 columns: country_code INT(3), state_code INT(3), town_code INT(3) and class VARCHAR(255)

In table_two I have 4 columns again:country_code INT(3), state_code INT(3), town_code INT(3) and name VARCHAR(255).

The two tables cant be merged because I will need to add columns to each in the future as they serve different purposes.

I am trying to write a sql query to eventually get a list/tuple of the following data: country_code, state_code, town_code, class, name. I am looking for a solution to query all the students in a specific state using table_one and then search the 3 identifying codes of those students to get their names in table_two for each student. I have tried using JOIN and UNION commands but I cant seem to get it to work yet.

```
Sample Data

table_one
country_code      state_code    town_code    class
    001              004           001         9
    074              006           003         3
    001              003           001         7

table_two
country_code      state_code    town_code    name
    001              004           001       John Doe
    074              006           003       Jane Doe
    001              003           001       First Last
```

The part I need help with:
Query (Not in SQL syntax): Find the country_code, state_code, town_code, class and name of all the students who live in country_code = 001

```
Expected Result
country_code      state_code    town_code    class      name
    001              004           001         9        John Doe
    001              003           001         7        First Last
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results and the code you tried could help.

Comment: So what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an inner join:

```
select t1.*, t2.name
from table_one t1 inner join table_two t2
on t2.country_code = t1.country_code and t2.state_code = t1.state_code and t2.town_code = t1.town_code
```

You may add a WHERE clause to apply your conditions

Comment: Initially i couldn't get it to work so I tried the other solution which worked but then tried your solution again and it worked and ended up sticking with it because its simpler, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Z.Chen the answers are exactly the same. How this didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

A simple join is enough:

```
    SELECT a.country_code,
           a.state_code,
           a.town_code,
           a.class,
           b.name
      FROM table_one a
      JOIN table_two b
        ON a.country_code = b.country_code
       AND a.state_code = b.state_code
       AND a.town_code = b.town_code
     WHERE a.country_code = ?
```

output:

`+--------------+------------+-----------+-------+------------+
| country_code | state_code | town_code | class | name       |
+--------------+------------+-----------+-------+------------+
|            1 |          4 |         1 | 9     | John Doe   |
|            1 |          3 |         1 | 7     | First Last |
+--------------+------------+-----------+-------+------------+`